# Series with $\zeta$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, riemann-zeta

How do I calculate the following series:

$$ \zeta(2)+\zeta(3)+\zeta(4)+ \dots + \zeta(2013) + \zeta(2014) $$

All I know is that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ and $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$. But this is not enough to solve this problem. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\eqalign{\sum_{j=2}^N \zeta(j) &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=2}^N \dfrac{1}{n^j}\cr  &= N-1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty  \dfrac{n^{-1} - n^{-N}}{n-1}\cr
&= N - 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^{-N}}{n-1}} $$
Now $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{n}\right) = 1$$
while
$$0 < \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^{-N}}{n-1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^{1-N}}{n(n-1)} < 2^{1-N} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} = 2^{1-N}$$
so that

$$N > \sum_{j=2}^N \zeta(j) > N - 2^{1-N} $$

Comment: This is nice. (+1)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. A good generalization. But can you finish off the problem, or is @yangapatel's method okay?

Comment: What do you mean by "finish off"?  In the case at hand, $N=2014$, the approximation is $2014$.  It's a very good approximation, since $2^{1-2014}$ is about $10^{-606}$.  But an exact "closed form" formula better than what you started with is not to be expected.

Comment: Oh. I see. Got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Note that $\zeta(n)-1>0 $ for $n>1$.
First we need to show that:
$$\sum_{n\mathop=2}^{\infty} \zeta(n)-1=1$$

> **Proof for $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n)-1) = 1$:**
>
> Use $ \displaystyle\zeta(n) - 1 =  \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^n} - 1 = \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^n}$ to get
> $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n)-1) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^n} $
> $$ =  \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^n}= \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s(s-1)}= \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}\bigg)=1$$

Therefore:
$$0<\sum_{n\mathop=2}^{2014}\zeta(n)-1<1$$
$$2013<\sum_{n\mathop=2}^{2014}\zeta(n)<2014$$
$${\sum_{n\mathop=2}^{2014}\zeta(n)}\approx 2014$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha confirms this solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D2+to+2014+of+zeta%28n%29

Comment: This is very solid!  +1 ... just curious, but where had you seen this before?  The bound is clear, but, but where did the 4-digit approximation come from?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Since $\zeta(n)-1=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\ldots$, $$\sum_{n>2014}(\zeta(n)-1)=\frac{2}{2^{2015}}+\frac{3/2}{3^{2015}}+\ldots \leq 2\left(\zeta(2015)-1\right)$$ that is extremely small.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you once again. I haven't seen this exact question before, but I have seen the above proof. As for your question, the solution is close to but less than 2014. And this can be verified by using mathematica, which yields an answer 2013.9999...6699228. However, in this case I think that OP was looking for an approximate form which is 2014 in this case. I

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Should I take out the 2013.9999...  and leave it as 2014? Like I just did?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, but I was asking specifically where the approximation came from.  Just a numerical computation, but precisely of what nature?